# Extra disk with 0 byte of storage showing on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, apfs, hfs

[image]I have a 2017 MacBook Pro 15". I recently removed a windows partition. Now the disk utility is showing an HFS+ volume with 0 bytes of storage. I tried to remove it using disk utility, recovery mode, terminal and by booting into safe mode. But nothing has resolved the issue. [image]

Comment: How exactly did you try to remove it?  Booting into Safe Mode is just the first step.  It’s like saying “I need to fix a problem at work and I tried entering the building, calling the operator and going round back.” What exactly did you try and what failed?

Comment: Please open Terminal and type diskutil list > listdisk.txt. Then do diskutil APFS list > apfslist.txt. Then post the results by editing your question. The graphical Disk Utility doesn’t show everything.

Comment: I tried to remove it using disk utility in safe mood and recovery mood. I am running Big Sur on one drive and Cataline on the other. Tried both of them.

Comment: Here is the terminal list